# Android app upload on google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded an app on Google play store. After uploading i made minor changes in the app. Is there a way to apply those changes to the play store?
Do i have to upload a new apk or create a new version of the app ?

Comment: of course you need to do for each change that you want to made available in play store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update your apps**

***Prepare your APK***

When you're ready to make changes to your APK, make sure to update your app’s Version Code as well so that existing users will receive your update.
Use the following checklist to make sure your new APK is ready to update your existing users:

- The Package Name of the updated APK needs to be the same as the
  current version.
- The Version Code needs to be greater than that current version. Learn
  more about versioning your applications.
- The updated APK needs to be signed with the same signature as the
  current version.

To verify that your APK is using the same certification as the previous version, you can run the following command on both APKs and compare the results:

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

If the results are identical, you’re using the same key and are ready to continue. If the results are different, you will need to re-sign the APK with the correct key.

**Learn more about signing your applications :-**

***Upload your APK***

Once your APK is ready, here’s how you can upload the new version using your Developer Console.

1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select your app.
3. On the left menu, click APK .
4. Click the Upload new APK button.
5. Upload your APK.
6. Select a publishing option.

***Delivery of updates***

After you've submitted an update to an app, you’ll see “Update pending” near the top right of your app’s Developer Console pages while your app is being processed. Once the update is published, your update will start being distributed to existing users and the “Update pending” status won’t be displayed.

Once your update is available, users can download the update on your app’s Store Listing page or from their

***My apps page on the Play Store app.***

Also, if a user has turned on automatic updates for your app, the update will be downloaded and installed automatically.
App updates take some time to be delivered to existing users. If you've submitted an update that hasn't showed up on Google Play, please wait at least 24 hours before contacting our support team.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

You have to increase the version code and have to create new signed apk.

Steps:

1. Make your project ready for publish (remove logs, remove unused import statement and resources etc.)
2. Increase version code in manifest file. You can increase version name but its not mandatory, its depend upon the changes you are doing in the application.
3. Generate signed `APK` with your `.keystore` or `.jks` file.
4. Upload `APK` on Play Store.

Go through this [link](http://support.andromo.com/kb/distributing/how-to-update-your-app-in-google-play) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , You can update an existing app w/o changing its version name. The version name is what the user will see on Google Play (i.e. version 1.10, 2.08, etc.), and has nothing to do with the actual version number of your application (it can be anything you want).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) you have to increment your app version and upload the new APK. I recommend reading this article to get an overview of all instructions to update your app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do changes. After finished changes, you just need to increase version code and generate new signed bundle for your app.

Create new release in google play console and roll out it.It will be mirrored with in few hours in playstore.